# Is it possible to read Lucene.NET index segments in parallel?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

And how?

I use standart FSDirectory's IndexReader and Collector over it to collect the results, but now I see that most of my time during read is spent in `Lucene.Net.Index.SegmentTermEnum.Next()`.

The read is performed in single thread and since the server has 8 cores i want to load them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only built in solution I can think of is to split you index in several sub indices and use a [ParallelMultiSearcher](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_2/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/ParallelMultiSearcher.html) to search in them, but I'm pretty sure you'll see performances decrease as Lucene is typically IO bound and not CPU bound.

Also keep in mind that if you'd use all cores for a single search, you might experience horrible performance when serving multiple queries in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you split it the result in different threads, that all read from the same IndexReader?